# .NET Core - How to include package without nuget

Tags: .net, .net-core, package, nuget

I'm new to developing with .NET and .NET Core and until now I just used Nuget when I needed a package.

But now I want to include MapBoxNet into my project (https://github.com/AliFlux/MapboxNet) which doesn't have a Nuget package. As you can see, the Github repository just consists of a Visual Studio Solution. When opened I'm greeted with error messages and to be honest I really don't know what to do from here on.

Am I supposed to compile it myself, convert it to nuget package myself or is there a way to just include the MaBoxNetWPF folder into my own project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include it in your `MyProjectName.csproj` file like so:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web or whatever appropriate for your project">

  Other stuff...

  <ItemGroup>
    Other packages...
    <PackageReference Include="Mapbox.Sdk.Core" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  Perhaps even more stuff...

</Project>
```

Then you either restore (or run which does restore implicitly) your project.

EDIT:
I may have misread your question. If what you wish is to reference some other project `projB` in your project `projA` and `projB` does not have any Nuget packages available, you could pull it and either:
a) build Nuget package yourself and reference it locally
b) reference `projB` directly:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="../modules/projB/projB.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks, your edit covered what I was looking for. Turns out I just searched for the wrong terms and referencing another project like you suggested was all I was looking for.
Though I had to add the MapBoxNet Project to my project as a reference before Visual Studio could find the csproj.

Answer (score 1):

for dev purposes, yes, you can tag the project to create a nuget package on build and use it locally. But if you intend to use some sort of CI/CD pipeline the nuget package needs to be located on some nuget server which is reachable by the build server.